# Regarding the use of non-compliant and unconventional connectors in route to a 120v outlet receptacle?

Tags: connector, wiring, diy

I'm not sure how to word this so bear with me thank you.

I'm rewiring my generic 65w Pen style soldering iron power cable and it would be very convenient if I could first solder it onto a 1/4" guitar style male and female connector set in order t to make disconnecting and reconnecting easier for portability sake.     I'm trying to connect it to my 3d printer and while it's connected the power line needs to be secured into the cable bundle.   I chose the 1/4" connector because it's common I have a few male and female pairs available.  It's also the most rigid and beefy type of connector pair for the 2 lane connector types I have saved up in my connector stash.

Otherwise, I have the regular 3 lane type with grounding commonly found in power supply AC connections but it's not the right physical profile for my ideal solution.

I know it'll work at least in the short term but I don't know the long-term hazard potential as in heating up and starting a fire.   Could someone with knowledge chime in on the danger level here?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use an audio jack for 120 V AC mains?!! Ehmmm ....

Comment: Keep in mind that 1/4" phone plugs and jacks typically short the contacts together in the process of plugging or unplugging.

Comment: Danger level = Extreme

Comment: I foresee a fire and a lawsuit, possibly electrocution.

Comment: @DaveTweed that should probably be an answer. That makes these particular connectors absolutely 100% unsuitable full stop period regardless of any other concerns. If you plug or unplug it while the power is on you'll make a big spark and trip the breaker.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback, I figured I should ask before I used those connectors because I know it's not the right way to do it, but I was crossing my fingers for an "aesthetically ergonomic" solution.   I'll be the first to admit hindsight seems stupid but hindsight is 2020.  I feel it's in bad spirit to downvote an honest question, especially concerning safety.    I've always been told there's no stupid questions except the one's I don't ask.   I wonder what if I had gone ahead without asking, and what if I do that next time because I'm self-conscious about feeling judgement.

Comment: A soldering station that comes with a detachable, low-voltage iron may be more suitable for this.

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close. While the close/down-votes might be reactionary to a terrible idea, this is actually a _good_ question. I would much prefer someone ask an experienced community about this type of thing before endeavoring to implement it. Further, @MagicMath has added comments indicating what they've learned. I imagine other inexperienced electronics hobbyists and makers benefitting from this question/answer(s).

Answer (score 4):

Besides for the obvious safety reasons why this is completely unsafe and shoud never be attempted to begin with, 1/4" connectors are usually not rated for 120VAC.

Answer (score 1):

There are standard connectors that are designed for AC power, and that are rated for that application. Specifically, the international standard is the [IEC 60320 connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320). Among them, I recommend the [C13 and C14](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=exterior_conn&u=exterior_power_conn&o=std_ac_power_conn&f=iec_60320_ac_power_conn&s=C13-C14%20E-F) (my site). You can find two in-line plugs, one male (with pins, top one in the picture), one female (with sockets, bottom one). Wire the male to the soldering iron, and the female to the AC power source.

[image]

Comment: ah the good old "are the pins male or the casing?" argument. To clarify: *the one where you can touch the pins* must not be wired to the mains. Because you could touch the pins.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that there are people who confuse an actual female connector as a "male". I edited my answer to clarify the gender.

Comment: my urethra does not make me female and nor does it make sense for them to label these connectors this way (even though they did)

Answer (score 0):

Soldering irons are normally grounded.  Even if it weren't completely the wrong connector for the job, a 2 terminal connector would be unsuitable.